# selenium could not open firefox browser says NoclassDefFound error

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

We are using selenium 3.0.1 with gecko driver (v0.11.1) and firefox version 49 . when we are trying to trigger firefox browser using this code

```
     System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",gecko_driver_path );
     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();        
     driver.manage().window().maximize();
     return driver;
```

we are getting this error

```
     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/SessionNotFoundException
     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
     at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:37)
```

Please help me .

Comment: can you please share the code you tried?

Comment: @Naveen i have added my firefox trigger code . Please look into it

Comment: Did you add selenium-standalone-server-version.jar into your project?

Comment: i am using maven . so i have added selenium-java jar through dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add selenium-standalone server jar dependency as follows:

> If you are using DefaultSelenium (or the RemoteWebDriver implementation), you still need to start a Selenium server. The best way is to download the selenium-server-standalone.jar from the Selenium Downloads page and just use it. Furthermore you can also embed the Selenium server into your own project, if you add the following dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Reference:

1. http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/maven.jsp